# Java: Interpret byte array as object

Tags: java, sockets, object

I am receiving an object from a socket in a Java client. How can I interpret the received byte array as an object defined in my Java client?

All I know is how the object looks on the sender system in terms of the bit size of the individual variables.

Comment: How did that "object" get converted to bytes in the first place?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't exactly know. The socket send function just takes the address and size of the buffer and sends it.

Comment: If you don't know how the object is represented, then you can't possibly write conversion code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the format.

**You might use deserialization or if there is custom serialization technique, interpret the bytes by yourself.**

Comment: What kind of ways are there in Java to interpet the bytes by myself? I thought some sort of casting would be the solution. But it seems that casting a byte array to a class is not allowed in Java.

Comment: That is only applicable if you will use custom serialization. E.g. first 4 bytes represent the age field, etc. But you need to obviously know the serialization protocol.

Comment: Okay thanks. I understand I need to find out more about serializiation protocol on the sender side.

Answer (score 0):

you need is a method to convert from byte to object like below

```
public static Object deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
return is.readObject();
}
```

If your class extends `Serializable`, you can write and read objects through a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

or use `serialize` and `deserialize` methods in `SerializationUtils` from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).